# closed womrhole in space time

Tags: wormholes

Suppose there is a wormhole solution in space-time, so there is an entrance $A$ and an exit $B$. What happen if we put the entrance $A$ and the exit $B$ at the same point in space-time? What would a person see if they enter the wormhole?

The same place but with a different time, i.e. the exit $B$ is 10 years before the entrance $A$ and we put the entrance and exit glued together.

Comment: I don't understand the premise. If you have both at the same point in space-time, that means that $(t,x,y,z)$ are identical, not that $t$ differs as your last sentence suggests. Or are you asking for the two separate cases?

Comment: 2 separates cases, when the entrance and exit are at the same point and at the same time and when they are at the same space point but different time

Comment: I'm assuming your second question boils down to 'can we travel through time'.

Comment: Is this a physics question or a science fiction question?

Answer (score 0):

Wormholes are not that easy to manipulate, and not that easy to create. So let's imagine some theoretical possibilities. Keep in mind none of this has in any way been found, seen or firmly been theoretically placed on firm enough grounds that serious physicists think it's inevitable there are wormholes. There may not be.

The Wikipedia article on it talks about some possibilities, all theoretical. Yes, a wormhole would be possible, theoretically, and could be transversable (go in the black hole side, come out of the while hole side) if the neck of it is made up or or includes exotic matter. Exotic matter is matter that has never been detected, and that would have probably negative pressure, and would violate the positive energy conditions. Theoretically some postulated quantum fields could do that. None seen.

See wiki at  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole

Then theoretically one mouth could be at one spacetime point and the other at another. There is no hard constraints on what tHe relationship between those two spacetime points can be, so theoretically they could be right next to each other spatially but at different times. Maybe they could even be at the same spatial coordinate, but since spacetime is relativistic and mixes space and time in another coordinate system they might not be. As the wiki article has it, one can conceive of what are called closed timelike curves (CTC) that basically means you travel back in time, and then the e would be the paradox where you kill you father before you're conceived.

Those paradoxes are unresolved and if any CTC appear in a solution of general relativity, with or without quantum fields, the understanding is that it might be a non-physical solution. It would break the laws of causality. Anything could come out of anywhere with no warning, a tiger or your dead grandmother could appear right in front of you from thin air. Not sure which would scare you more.

So, yes, wormholes are fun, but we still don't know if really possible and it's real constraints. So it is to a great extent theorizing to see the theory's limits, and beyond that it is science fiction. Great movies, and physicists can be advisors.